# Passing request scoped beans from one page to another

Tags: spring, jsf-2, scope, request

If I have a request scope bean on a page in JSF2....how do I pass it to another page (I'm using JSF2 with Spring)?

I've tried the following but it doesnt work:

```
<h:commandButton action="complete.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"  value="Confirm Booking">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{quoteHolder.item}" value="#{quoteHolder.item}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> action="complete.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"
> ```

You're sending a redirect. The `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` won't help much here as the request scoped bean will be garbaged after the invoke action phase anyway.

You have basically the following options:

1. Send all the data as request parameter(s) instead (conversion to/from `String` necessary!)
2. Don't send a redirect (the `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` becomes superfluous then)
3. Store it in a session scoped bean (not recommended! may be bad for user experience).